# NoMachine cannot connect to Debian server, error 138

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, nomachine-nx, nomachine

I can't connect to the KDE GUI installed on my Debian server, using NoMachine. Connection over SSH (Both through PuTTy as X forwarding) works just fine, but somehow I can't figure out how to connect using NoMachine and the NX protocol.

I installed the NoMachine server on my Debian server (nomachine_5.1.54_1_amd64.deb), which seems to work fine. It listens on port 4000. I disabled the firewall on the server.

Then I installed NoMachine on my windows system and tried to connect to the server, using the same IP address as with the ssh connection, and the login credentials I use to login on the server.

I approach the server from another network, using a VPN connection and the HTTP proxy for the network connection.

I tried the tips provided online, but can't get it to work. I still get the error message:

```
Could not connect to the server.
Error is 138: Connection timed out
```

Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same IP address that is shown in the Welcome GUI like the attached image (taken from the nomachine website)
[nomachine welcome gui showing where to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzPN2.jpg)

Comment: Thx for your answer @Richard. Is this IP address different than the one I use for the SSH connection? How can I obtain the external IP address within linux, some command or config file?

Comment: By the way: no ip address is shown in the GUI on the client side.